# MySQL PHP search database and display output

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, left-join

User input - `<input type="text" name="name">`

I want to take the user input 'name' and display the transactionID relating to that customer, along with songname and artistname

### my database looks like this

- artists
- customers - last name or 'name' in here
- songs
- transactions - trans_ID and customer_ID in here
- transaction_details - trans_ID and song_ID in here

The query I've been using is structured like this

$q = `"SELECT customers.last_name, FROM customers
LEFT JOIN transactions ON customers.customer_ID = transactions.customer_ID
LEFT JOIN songs ON songs.song_ID = transaction_details.song_ID
WHERE customers.last_name LIKE '$lname%' AND customers.first_name LIKE '$name%";`

`$name = $_POST['name'];`

I want it to display:
transaction_ID + song_name + artist_name

- relating to the customer that was searched for..

Does anyone one know how I could possibly achieve what I need? 
It would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're missing a few things in your `SELECT` statement, like columns and tables and join clauses.  You might want to check out some introductory tutorials on MySQL.

Comment: I've revised it now, can you understand what I need now?

Comment: You have a syntax error, an extra comma before the `FROM`.  When executing database queries you should always check for errors from the database.  As for the rest of the question, if you want it to display `transaction_ID`, `song_name`, and `artist_name` then you'll need to select those columns from the data.  Then in the results, show those values in the output.  Again, introductory tutorials cover this stuff.  It's not really clear what you've tried or where you're stuck.

Comment: @user3277507 is name input  search for both last name and first name?

Comment: yes it is. But I've got the variables working fine I just need to come up with a query that will work

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use jquery Autocomplete or go through the url :-http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ 
    <script>
        $(function() {
            function log(message) {
                $("<div>").text(message).prependTo("#log");
                $("#log").scrollTop(0);
            }
            $("#search").autocomplete({
                minLength: 1,
                source: 'action.php',
            })
                    .autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
                if (item.fname) {
                    if (item.photo) {
                        return $("<li style='padding: 0px;'' href='/user-profile?user=" + item.id + "'>")
                                .append("<a style='margin: 0px; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;' href='/user-profile?user=" + item.id + "'><img src = '{{CLIENT_ROOT_PATH}}/assests/img/profile/thumbnail-130x130/" + item.photo + "' width =30 />   " + item.fname + " " + item.lname + "</a>")
                                .appendTo(ul);
                    }
                } else {
                    return $("<li>")
                            .append("<a href='#'> No result found</a>")
                            .appendTo(ul);
                }
            };
        });
    </script>



    And here the HTML :-

    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control" id="search">



    on action.php page return the required value in array form.
```